# Crear varias Gridview dinámicamente en tiempo de ejecución?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, gridview

C# asp.net
Tengo una Lista  de objetos "a" y cada uno de estos contiene una Lista  de objetos "b" dentro.

El asunto es que quiero mostrar una GridView por cada objeto a, los datos anidados de cada uno de estos rellenaran la grilla.

El tema de recorrer con foreach etc, está claro.
El problema es como crear grillas dinámicamente y posicionarla correctamente. Como la cantidad de objetos "a" es variable necesito crear la cantidad necesaria.

- Las grillas las cargo manualmente con el Datasource.
  No la tengo con SQL SQL directamente.
- Si hay una solución mejor (usando o no grillas) recomiendemela

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La descripción es un poco genérica... Pero con base en lo que describes, puedes almacenar los objetos 'a' en un Collection. Al ser de tamaño variable, no tendrás problemas en almacenar los objetos 'a' que requieras...
Por otro lado, puedes tener un método que imprima los objetos 'b' de cada objeto 'a'. Este método puede recibir como parámetro la posición vertical
Finalmente, cuando llegue el momento de imprimir los GridView, sólo sería necesario invocar el método que imprime los objetos 'b' de cada objeto 'a', pasándole como parámetro la posición vertical que se iría actualizando con loop...

Comment: Gracias, si tengo los objetos 'a' en colecciones, y los objetos "b" son atributos de cada a, en colecciones también. No entendí bien tu solución, pero yo necesito listar todo en el mismo momento, por lo tanto, y según como lo entiendo si lo hago así solo actualizaria la fuente de datos de la grilla y le cambiaría la posición. El problema es que no se tampoco cuantas GridView voy a necesitar.

Comment: Lo que te propongo es lo siguiente:

Comment: Dentro de la claseA, donde están definidos los objetos 'a', implementa un método que imprima los objetos 'b' del objeto 'a' en un nuevo GridView...

Cuando necesites hacer la impresión, (en tiempo de ejecución) mandarás llamar el método mencionado para cada objeto 'a' de tu Collection (ahí puedes aplicar el for each)... En ese momento, cada GridView se irá presentando, independientemente de la cantidad de objetos 'a' que tengas... Si requieres que estén en una posición vertical específica, esta se puede calcular dinámicamente dentro del for-each...